# Interactive unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, jupyter, python-interactive

I am new to python, and I am working on code that displays the ball at the timestamps on a graph. I want to use interactive widget to display how the ball moves on the graph.

```
def f(x):
    return matplotlib.pyplot.plot(ball.posx[x],ball.posy[x],'bo', markersize=5) #displaying current 
    
interactive(f, x=5);
```

however, I get this error message:

```
interactive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

But this is what it said in the documentation. How can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is `interactive`…?

Comment: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html

Comment: Looks like `interact` takes `x` but `interactive` takes `a`  and `b`. Try using `interact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added line: from ipywidgets import interact, interactive->interact